# Why it's in infinite loop?

Tags: c

```
I want to take input of integer and want to check that input is only one integer. So I have implemented some logic. But it's in infinite loop.
```

Logic is: if the scanf returns 1 that means it's a match and if not then it is not an integer and as the number should be greater than 5 so I have added that checking too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //Variable Declarations
    int a[1000],n,i,j,int_check=0;

    //Input for number of terms and it should be at least 5
    printf("Enter the number of terms for the array input:");
    int_check=scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nscanf=%d and n=%d\n",int_check,n);

    //Input Validity checking. If scanf returns 1 that means it's a match with the input. Number of terms should be greater than 5.
    while(int_check!=1 || n<5)
    {
    printf("Enter the valid number of terms for the array inout. It should be an integer and greater than 5:");
    int_check=scanf("%d",&n);   

    }

    return 0;

}
```

It should provide one input screen. Help me to identify what's wrong in this logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you do not enter a valid integer for `scanf("%d",...);` the unvalid input is *not* removed so you will get it in the next `scanf("%d",...);` so `(int_check!=1 || n<5)` will never be false

you need to flush the invalid input by yourself, warning do not use `fflush(stdin);` because that works only on file

Note to see the message you need to flush it, for instance replace

> ```
>     printf("Enter the valid number of terms for the array inout. It should be an integer and greater than 5:");
> ```

by

```
    printf("Enter the valid number of terms for the array inout. It should be an integer and greater than 5:\n");
```

or use  `fflush(stdout);` after the *printf* is you prefer to stay on the same line

Comment: But the expectation is it should ask me to enter the input again. Why not it's asking. Instead, it's in infinite loop.

Comment: @DipakChatterjee because as said the input is **not** removed, you need to remove it by yourself, for instance reading char by char up to the \n (also managing the EOF case)

Comment: @DipakChatterjee you do not see the message because you missed to output a newline to flush it

Comment: Rather than relying on `fflush(stdin)` (the behaviour is not defined in Standard C or even POSIX) prefer `fgets()` possibly followed by `sscanf()`.

Comment: @pmg you read wrongly, I said to the OP to **not** use `fflush(stdin)` ;-)

Comment: Oops... my bad, sorry @bruno. Anyway, I'll leave the comment for the common replacement.

Comment: @pmg no problem, I use glasses and even with them I can read wrongly too ^^

Comment: while(int_check!=1 || n<5)
 {
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("\nEnter the valid number of terms for the array input.\n It should be an integer and greater than 5:");
 int_check=scanf("%d",&n); 
  
 }

Comment: @DipakChatterjee `fflush(stdout)` works, but generally `ffluch(stdin)` does not work and to suppose it works is not portable. The description is : _For  input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files,
       but **not** pipes or terminals), fflush()  discards  any  buffered  data
       that  has  been  fetched  from the underlying file, but has not been
       consumed by the application._